# how to build linkedin bot using puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

**I want to build a LinkedIn automatic request sender.**

Task to do?

1. open linkedin.com
2. login into LinkedIn using login details
3. Do search for people with the keyword
4. send a connection request with a note.
   I am unable t

   ````
   const select = require('puppeteer-select');
   const FORM = {
       USERNAME_SELECTOR: '#username',
       PASSWORD_SELECTOR: '#password',
       BUTTON_SELECTOR: '.btn__primary--large.from__button--floating'
   };
   const CREDENTIALS = {
       USERNAME: 'Username',
       PASSWORD: 'password'
   };
   const SEARCH = {
       SEARCH_SELECTOR: '#global-nav-search',
       KEYWORD: '',
       CONNECT: '#ember52'
   };

   const escapeXpathString = str => {
     const splitedQuotes = str.replace(/'/g, `', "'", '`);
     return `concat('${splitedQuotes}', '')`;
   };

   const clickByText = async (page, text) => {
     const escapedText = escapeXpathString(text);
     const linkHandlers = await page.$x(`//a[contains(text(), ${escapedText})]`);

     if (linkHandlers.length > 0) {
       await linkHandlers[0].click();
     } else {
       throw new Error(`Link not found: ${text}`);
     }
   };

   (async () => {
     const browser = await puppeteer.launch(); 
     const page = await browser.newPage();
     await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/login?trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
     await page.click(FORM.USERNAME_SELECTOR);
     await page.keyboard.type(CREDENTIALS.USERNAME);
     await page.click(FORM.PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
     await page.keyboard.type(CREDENTIALS.PASSWORD);
     await page.click(FORM.BUTTON_SELECTOR);
     await page.waitForNavigation();
     await page.click(SEARCH.SEARCH_SELECTOR);
     await page.focus(SEARCH.SEARCH_SELECTOR);
     await page.keyboard.type(SEARCH.KEYWORD);
     await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
     await page.waitForNavigation();
     clickByText(page,`people`);
     await page.waitForNavigation();
     await page.screenshot({path: 'verify16.png', fullPage: true});

     console.log("Current page:", page.url());
    //from here
     const invitation = await select(page).getSend('span:contains(Send)');
   await invitation.click();
   //getting error
     await browser.close();
   })();```
   ````

I cannot click on connect button -> I have also to add notes and do for all other connections.

Answer (score 0):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const select = require('puppeteer-select');
const FORM = {
    USERNAME_SELECTOR: '#username',
    PASSWORD_SELECTOR: '#password',
    BUTTON_SELECTOR: '.btn__primary--large.from__button--floating'
};
const CREDENTIALS = {
    USERNAME: 'user',
    PASSWORD: 'password'
};
const SEARCH = {
    SEARCH_SELECTOR: '#global-nav-search',
    KEYWORD: 'keyword',
    CONNECT: '#ember52'
};

const escapeXpathString = str => {
  const splitedQuotes = str.replace(/'/g, `', "'", '`);
  return `concat('${splitedQuotes}', '')`;
};

const clickByText = async (page, text) => {
  const escapedText = escapeXpathString(text);
  const linkHandlers = await page.$x(`//a[contains(text(), ${escapedText})]`);
  
  if (linkHandlers.length > 0) {
    await linkHandlers[0].click();
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Link not found: ${text}`);
  }
};

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(); 
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/login?trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
  await page.click(FORM.USERNAME_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(CREDENTIALS.USERNAME);
  await page.click(FORM.PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(CREDENTIALS.PASSWORD);
  await page.click(FORM.BUTTON_SELECTOR);
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.click(SEARCH.SEARCH_SELECTOR);
  await page.focus(SEARCH.SEARCH_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(SEARCH.KEYWORD);
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  clickByText(page,`people`);
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.screenshot({path: `verifytest.png`, fullPage: true});
  const [button] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Connect')]");
if (button) {
    await button.click();
}
const [buttonNote] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Add a note')]");
if (buttonNote) {
    await buttonNote.click();
}
await page.keyboard.type('Pardon! buddy i am just testing my bot ~ Manvendra Yadav');
const [buttonSendNote] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Send')]");
if (buttonSendNote) {
    await buttonSendNote.click();
}
let elements = await page.$$('#main > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > ul > li');
// loop trough items
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      const [button] = await elements[i].$x("//button[contains(., 'Connect')]");
if (button) {
    await button.click();
}
const [buttonNote] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Add a note')]");
if (buttonNote) {
    await buttonNote.click();
}
await page.keyboard.type('Pardon! buddy i am just testing my bot ~ Manvendra Yadav');
await page.screenshot({path: `verify${i}.png`, fullPage: true});
const [buttonSendNote] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Send')]");
if (buttonSendNote) {
    await buttonSendNote.click();
}
}
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).